# Inner properties of an object type attribute in lightning is not visible when passed in to child components when lightning debug mode is enabled

Tags: lightning-aura-components

In a lightning component when an attribute of type Object[] is passed to a child component, the inner properties of the object is not visible when lightning debug mode is enable. If lightning debug mode is disabled the component works fine.

```
<!--Parent component-->
<aura:attribute name="test" type="Object[]" default="[]" />
The values of test are formed dynamically in helper of parent component
<aura:if isTrue="{! v.test.length > 0}">
<c:childComponent childTestArray="{!v.test}" />
</aura:if>


<!--Child Component-->
<aura:attribute name="childTestArray" default="[]" type="Object[]"/>
```

Now lets say the each element in test array if of type 
   {'property1':'','property2':''}. I'm getting an error that says, "
  Access Check Failed! AttributeSet.get(): attribute 'property1' of component 'markup://aura:if {892:0}' is not visible to 'markup://childComponent {891:0}'"

This is not the exact component markup but just a gist. I get the error only when lightning debug mode is enabled. If debug mode is disabled, the component works fine. I just want the component to be tested thoroughly hence was trying with lightning debug mode enabled. Is there anything I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `{'property1':'','property2':''}` is a JS Object and not a JS array, so matching it to `Object[]` doesn't make sense.  Consider using just `Object`

Comment: Yes that's what I meant, each element in the array is of that structure. And when the array is under iteration(aura iteration) and debug mode is enabled, I'm getting that error

Comment: I would post some of the original code - I think the issue is really going to be in the details